# Get list of holders of a token using Cardano-cli or Cardano-DB-Sync or Ogmios

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-db-sync, token, query

I am trying to find a way using either Cardano-cli, Ogmios, or Cardano-DB-Sync to get a list of token holders (addresses) for a particularly token, ideally in JSON format.

What is the best way to do this **without** using an explorer or API like blockfrost?

Answer (score 2):

"List of holders" is rather unclear. If you want names, addresses and other KYC/AML stuff you won't be able to get it. Tokens are held in Cardano addresses, and any person could have more than one address, and given two addresses, there is no general way to validate that the addresses do or do not belong to the same person.

However, you can get all the addresses that hold a particular token from `cardano-db-sync` with a relatively simple SQL query.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify, I am looking for a list of cardano addresses

Answer (score 1):

You can use Koios endpoint documented [here](https://api.koios.rest/#get-/asset_address_list), and if you run a dbsync instance, you can find the dbsync query used [here](https://github.com/cardano-community/guild-operators/blob/alpha/files/grest/rpc/assets/asset_address_list.sql)